# *When* do you save data from an edit control in a Xamarin Forms listview?

Tags: data-management, xamarin.forms.listview

I could not think of how to best phrase my question, so what you think I'm asking is probably not what I'm asking. Pretend that I've got three working apps, but the needs of this fourth one are a little different, so I'm asking for advice / best practices, not how to write an SQL statement, code a listview, customize a viewcell, or how to bind to a datamodel. I've got all that.

The TLDR version:

What I need is a sane way to know when the user is done entering his data so I can push it to my server.

I know that there are people out there who have solved this problem, so I'm soliciting your advice. If you also did not want to do a save on every keystroke, I'm especially interested in your recommendations.

Here's the slightly more detailed version:

I'm writing a companion app for part of our desktop software, which uses a proprietary data server to store its data that I can access from the mobile device. In my previous apps, I have a screenful of controls. The user enters/modifies data, and I know to save to my local sqlite table when they exit the screen. It's basically a transactional model, and I only upload the data to our server when they press a button to do so. Works great.

However, for this app, instead of entering a screenful of information, the user is just entering numbers in a list. Think inventory: user has a list of products and quantities, and they update the quantities to match what they've got. The user will not leave the data entry screen often, and is likely to turn off the device, or kick the app out of memory without "going back", so my datamodels can have unstored data.

I have entry fields in a listview. I need to push the entered data to my sqlite table, then on to our proprietary data server. I would have thought to do it from the property setter in my datamodel, but sadly that gets called when the datamodel is initially bound, AND on every keystroke.

I know that there are lots of people who have coded data entry in a listview, I've read all the posts to figure out how make the viewcells work. I am primarily using Entry controls, and I have tried using TextChanged, Completed, and Unfocused. Each one has some sort of issue that makes it an undesirable solution "out of the box". I've got some ideas and know how to solves parts of my problem, but am hoping someone out there has a much better solution than my collection of little hacks.

Obviously there's a ton of details (and complexity) I'm leaving out. I am using a view - viewmodel - model architecture, but am not using MVVM or any similar framework. My solution needs to be in "vanilla" Xamarin Forms.

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I would comment but I don't have enough reputation, so here it goes.

Is there a specific reason a button can not be added to the page (below the list view), so that the user can press it when they are done taking "inventory"? I'm assuming this is part of the complexity/details you are leaving out.

Without a button, you could make the data save/push happen using an Unfocused event on each entry field. If the user filled in a value for each entry control, the unfocus event could call the method to save the data. The code-behind would get a bit cluttered and it could be messy if you have a long list of entry controls, but it would get the job done until you find (or create) or better way.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, @Eric B. Our users won't hit an extra button unless I force them (it wouldn't be in the natural flow of how they use their device) so I am trying to figure out how to use an acr.userdialog prompt to enter the number, then I'd know when they're done entering.

Unfocused isn't always called. TextChanged isn't always called, either. So I wondered if I should be using a completely different approach. There's an awful lot about this flavor of object oriented programming that I don't know, so I thought I'd see if there was a better approach.

Comment: Rather than use an acr.userdialog, why not use a DisplayAlert? I know you mentioned you'd like to try and stay as close to "vanilla" Xamarin.Forms as possible, so that would allow you to prompt your user without an extra NuGet package. Maybe have it pop up after a few values have been entered instead of on every one.

Comment: Because DisplayAlerts do not provide the ability to enter a numeric value. Think inventory... Entering lots of numbers.

Comment: Ah, you're right. My apologies, that was an oversight on my behalf. I think at this point, if you wanted to meet your requirements and get closer to vanilla Xamarin, the solution provided by TheMaegges on this forum post may take to where you want to be: 
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/35838/how-to-do-a-simple-inputbox-dialog
Combining this implementation of a very customizable dialog box with a switch control the user can interact with to signal they are done entering inventory numbers might work.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I hadn't found that one yet. I'll have to weigh whether I want to try to get that working in my app, or use the Rg.Plugins.Popup NuGet package. I was really hoping that there was a more elegant, and simpler, solution.

Comment: Good luck. If you do figure it out, remember to update your post! Sorry I couldn't provide a definitive answer :P